# Laravel: why does this cause error - call to undefined method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Why calling a method with parenthesis in a template causes error, but without doesn't? How would I pass a parameter then?

Error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::test()
```

index.blade.php

```
...
<p class="product-price-old"><s>{{ $product->test("123") }}</s></p>
...
```

Product.php

```
...
public function getTestAttribute($value)
{
    return $value;
}
...
```

---

but if I do something like this it works fine:

index.blade.php

```
...
<p class="product-price-old"><s>{{ $product->test }}</s></p>
...
```

Product.php

```
...
public function getTestAttribute()
{
    return "123";
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getTestAttribute` is [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators), so it's not a real function. It rather shows how you can get attribute of model.

That's why for getTestAttribute method you should use:

```
$product->test
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are assigning an instance of Product.php (which should be a model of a product table in your database) to a blade variable, and your Product table has a column called 'test' , Then you're just printing that value from your model and the instance of Product.php does not have a test() method in it. You can just retrieve the value of `test` attribute.

If you want to pass parameters to a function in your model, Use a different name for your function. You can not pass parameters to `accessor`s in Laravel.